# How to create a trend query with first day of iteration as the start date?

Tags: charts, tfs

I am getting started with TFS 2015 and I need to know how to make a trend chart with the start of the iteration as the start date. I want to create a burndown chart for the iteration which shows the amount of story points remaining instead of the number of hours remaining. How can I create a customized iteration burndown chart?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunatelly this feature is not yet available for our on-premises TFS. It's available on VSTS. See [this **user voice**](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-visual-studio-team-services/suggestions/4473980-add-story-point-burndown-to-dashboard-and-reports) for details

So, we can not modify the Range (set the first day of iteration as the start date) for the trend query, we can only select the existing range, e.g. **Last seven days**, **Last two weeks** ...

However if you just want to track the amount of story points remaining, then you can create a query which list all the unclosed user stories, then add a new chart based on the query, then [add the chart to your project dashboard](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/report/dashboards/add-charts-to-dashboard#add-a-work-item-query-or-chart).

Another workaround is migrating to VSTS with [Analytics extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms.vss-analytics) installed, then add the **Burndown** widget to dashboard to set that based on your requirement.

> [***Source here:  Availability for Team Foundation Server (TFS)***](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/report/analytics/what-is-analytics#availability-for-team-foundation-server-tfs)
>
> **The Analytics Service is
> not yet available for our on-premises product, Team Foundation Server
> (TFS).** When we have information on when it will be available, we will
> update this page. Look for announcements on the Microsoft DevOps Blog.
>
> For TFS reporting, you may use Dashboards with a variety of widgets
> that don't require the Analytics Service. You may also use SQL Server
> Reporting. The future of reporting for both VSTS and TFS, however, is
> the Analytics Service.

[image]